# WinApplicationDriver get rows from datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, selenium, datagrid, appium

What i have:

```
namespace DataGrid
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = new ViewModelDataGrid();
        }
    }

    public class ViewModelDataGrid
    {
        public ObservableCollection<string> Items { get; set; }

        public ViewModelDataGrid()
        {
            Items = new ObservableCollection<string>();

            for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
            {
                Items.Add(i.ToString());
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Xaml

```
 <Grid>
        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Line No" Binding="{Binding .}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
```

Waht I am trying to do:

```
DesiredCapabilities appDataGridCapabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
appDataGridCapabilities.SetCapability("app", @"C:\Users\a\Documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\DataGrid\DataGrid\bin\Debug\DataGrid.exe");
appDataGridCapabilities.SetCapability("deviceName", "WPF");
var dataGridSession = new WindowsDriver<WindowsElement>(new Uri(@"http://127.0.0.1:4723"), appDataGridCapabilities);
dataGridSession.Manage().Window.Position = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
var elements = dataGridSession.FindElementByClassName("DataGrid").FindElementsByClassName("DataGridRow");
```

I am trying to get all rows from datagrid. But currently I get only those rows that displayed on a screen because of binding system and virtualization. Is it possible in some way get all rows from DataGrid that does not displayed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible in some way get all rows from `DataGrid` that does not displayed?

Only if you disable the virtualization in your application:

```
<DataGrid VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizing="False" ... />
```

There are no `DataGridRow` row containers for the rows that have been virtualized away available in memory and you cannot get a reference to an object that doesn't exist.

Comment: Very important to set `EnableRowVirtualization="False"` also.